# Google Earth Pro - create 3D plot from CSV with Longitude, Latitude and Altitude

Tags: google-earth

I have two CSV's with longitude, latitude and altitude data and I want to plot both with different colors in Google Earth Pro (so 3D). Is this even possible? If so, how can I do this? I can only find 2D plotting.

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want one set of placemarks to be in one color, and the other in another? In that case you should be able to select the placemarks imported from each CSV, and modify their styling or icon type following these instructions:
https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148142?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdrag-or-edit-the-placemark%2Cuse-a-custom-icon

If instead you're trying to set colors based on field values (e.g., altitude), you can create a style template as described her:
https://support.google.com/earth/answer/176685?hl=en#styletemplate&zippy=%2Cimport-generic-text-files%2Cmap-color-styles

HTH!